# How to add next previous button for thumbnail in this Bootstrap Product Slider?

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to have next and previous button for thumbnail part such that it could display more items in this Bootstrap Product slider showing only few thumbnails and navigate to every item using next and previous.

http://codepen.io/RetinaInc/details/FGjbH

This is how i tried but not worked as i wanted

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
       <h1>Products</h1>  
        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img class ="img-responsive" src="img/doubleRound/all-parts.JPG">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img class ="img-responsive" src="img/doubleRound/front_side.JPG">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img class ="img-responsive" src="img/doubleRound/front.JPG">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img  class ="img-responsive"src="img/doubleRound/top.JPG">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div> 
    </div> <!-- /col-sm-6 -->
    <div class="col-sm-6">


        <div class="clearfix">
              <div class="carousel-link">
              <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="thumb"><img class ="img-responsive" src="img/doubleRound/all-parts.JPG"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1" class="thumb"><img class ="img-responsive" src="img/doubleRound/front_side.JPG"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2" class="thumb"><img class ="img-responsive" src="img/doubleRound/front.JPG"></div>
                <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3" class="thumb"><img class ="img-responsive" src="img/doubleRound/top.JPG"></div>

      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>

              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly simple to do this with 2 separate carousels.

### [Bootply Demo Here.](http://www.bootply.com/u2HGq0HCpH)

The basic concept is that you have 2 separate carousels: One for the large images and a second for the thumbs.  The thumbs are simply items in the second carousel.  The trick is to make sure that you set the data-target on the thumb to the id of the first carousel.

I've also set the "thumb" carousel to not cycle on it's own.  If you wanted to have the thumb carousel cycle "in sync" with the first carousel, you could do that with a little js.  I'll try and update this later with an example of that.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/e8117f/fff&text=Product+Main">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/00ffff/000&text=Product+Image+2">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/ff00ff/fff&text=Product+Image+3">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/ffff00/000&text=Product+Image+4">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/e8117f/fff&text=Product+Image+5">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/00ffff/000&text=Product+Image+6">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/ff00ff/fff&text=Product+Image+7">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/ffff00/000&text=Product+Image+8">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div id="thumbcarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="thumb"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/e8117f/fff&text=Product+Main"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1" class="thumb"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/00ffff/000&text=Product+Image+2"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2" class="thumb"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/ff00ff/fff&text=Product+Image+3"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3" class="thumb"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/ffff00/000&text=Product+Image+4"></div>
                </div><!-- /item -->
                <div class="item">
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="4" class="thumb"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/e8117f/fff&text=Product+Image+5"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="5" class="thumb"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/00ffff/000&text=Product+Image+6"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="6" class="thumb"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/ff00ff/fff&text=Product+Image+7"></div>
                    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="7" class="thumb"><img src="http://placehold.it/100/ffff00/000&text=Product+Image+8"></div>
                </div><!-- /item -->
            </div><!-- /carousel-inner -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#thumbcarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#thumbcarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div> <!-- /thumbcarousel -->
    </div><!-- /clearfix -->
    </div> <!-- /col-sm-6 -->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h2>Products</h2>
        <h3>Some product subhead</h3>
        <p>Product description goes here.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
        <p>Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.</p>

    </div> <!-- /col-sm-6 -->
  </div> <!-- /row -->
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

**CSS:**

```
.item .thumb {
    width: 25%;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
}
.item .thumb img {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 2px;
}
.item img {
    width: 100%;    
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

**SYNC OPTION 1:** To keep the items in sync, you can use a jQuery to calculate how many items in the main carousel and how many are in the thumb carousel.  Then use that to calculate the position of the active slide in the main carousel within the thumb carousel.  This is dependent on your main images and thumb images being in the same order:

```
(function($){
    $('#thumbcarousel').carousel(0);
    var $thumbItems = $('#thumbcarousel .item');
    var $items = $('#carousel .item');
    var numItems = $items.length; 
    var numThumbItems = $thumbItems.length; 
    var thumbGroup = Math.ceil(numItems/numThumbItems); 
    $('#carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (event) {
        var curThumbIndex = $thumbItems.index($thumbItems.filter('.active').get(0));
        var activeSlideNum = $items.index(event.relatedTarget)+1;
        var thumbIndex = (Math.ceil(activeSlideNum/thumbGroup))-1;
        if (curThumbIndex>thumbIndex) {
            $('#thumbcarousel').one('slid.bs.carousel', function (event) {
                $('#thumbcarousel').carousel(thumbIndex);
            });
            if (curThumbIndex === ($thumbItems.length-1)) {
                $('#thumbcarousel').carousel('next');
            } else {
                $('#thumbcarousel').carousel(numThumbItems-1);
            }
        } else {
            $('#thumbcarousel').carousel(thumbIndex);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

---

**SYNC OPTION 2:**
I also updated the Bootply demo with a slightly different way of accomplishing this, **but this approach requires extra markup**.  In the Bootply demo, you'll see that you can set the thumb item target using data-thumb on each of the main carousel items. The number represents the zero-base index of the targeted item in the thumb carousel.  For example:

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active" data-thumb="0">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/e8117f/fff&amp;text=Product+Main">
        </div>
        <div class="item" data-thumb="0">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/00ffff/000&amp;text=Product+Image+2">
        </div>
        <div class="item" data-thumb="0">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/ff00ff/fff&amp;text=Product+Image+3">
        </div>
        <div class="item" data-thumb="0">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/ffff00/000&amp;text=Product+Image+4">
        </div>
        <div class="item" data-thumb="1">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/7B1C8E/fff&amp;text=Product+Image+5">
        </div>
        <div class="item" data-thumb="1">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/9EF383/000&amp;text=Product+Image+6">
        </div>
        <div class="item" data-thumb="1">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/D64908/fff&amp;text=Product+Image+7">
        </div>
        <div class="item" data-thumb="1">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/E3A3A1/000&amp;text=Product+Image+8">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you could use this script instead:

```
(function($){
    $('#thumbcarousel').carousel(0);
    var $thumbItems = $('#thumbcarousel .item');
    $('#carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (event) {
       var $slide = $(event.relatedTarget);
       var thumbIndex = $slide.data('thumb');
       var curThumbIndex = $thumbItems.index($thumbItems.filter('.active').get(0));
        if (curThumbIndex>thumbIndex) {
            $('#thumbcarousel').one('slid.bs.carousel', function (event) {
                $('#thumbcarousel').carousel(thumbIndex);
            });
            if (curThumbIndex === ($thumbItems.length-1)) {
                $('#thumbcarousel').carousel('next');
            } else {
                $('#thumbcarousel').carousel(numThumbItems-1);
            }
        } else {
            $('#thumbcarousel').carousel(thumbIndex);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. and i am waiting for your update. I want sync.

Comment: is it possible to get thumbnail part after the text paragraph on big screen but after the big carousal on smaller screen something like push and pull does?

Comment: Sure, why not?  It has no dependency on the containing elements so,  wrapping the #thumbcarousel in it's own col class is fine.  Then you can use the push/pull classes as needed to get your desired result.

Comment: I have little more to ask. I can i add a carousel caption div? I can't ask it in new question because i don't want to get banned. Currently My carousel caption is visible on small screen but not on desktop view. also I want caption to be on a div on overlaying on the carousel's image. Thank you in advance.